# Javascript appended code comes as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code where I take the submissions from a form and append it to a HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    div {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    input[type=text],
    textarea,
    select {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    input[type=button] {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: auto;
      float: right;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 7px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>


    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtAge" placeholder="Enter your age" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="selCountry">
        <option selected value="">-- Choose the country --</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Write some message ..." style="height:100px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="bt" value="Write" onclick="writeFile()" />
    </div>

  </div>
  
<p>Submission Number: <a id="clicks">1</a>

  <div class="output-area">
    <h4>Output</h4>
    <div id="output" class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span></span>

</body>
<script>
var clicks = 1;

  let writeFile = () => {

    const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
    const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    const submissions = document.getElementById('clicks');


    let data = [ 
      `<p>Name: ${name.value}</p>`, 
      `<p>Age: ${age.value}</p>`, 
      `<p>Email: ${email.value}</p>`,  
      `<p>Country: ${country.value}</p>`,  
      `<p>Message: ${msg.value}</p>`,  
      `<p>Submission No: ${submissions.value}</p>`];
 
   
    $('#output').append("<br />" + "<br />");

    data.forEach(line => $('#output').append(line));
clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }


</script>

</html>
```

In this code, I wanted to print the users' current submission number. So I made a click counter.

```
clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
```

And then I tried to put it into a constant and append it.

```
const submissions = document.getElementById('clicks');
```

But issue I'm facing here is, when appended my submission field comes out as `Submission No: undefined`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `submissions` element is an anchor (`<a>`) element. These HTML elements do not have a `value` field.

You can read the value the same way you are writing it, via `innerHTML`.

E.g.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    div {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    input[type=text],
    textarea,
    select {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    input[type=button] {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: auto;
      float: right;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 7px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>


    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtAge" placeholder="Enter your age" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="selCountry">
        <option selected value="">-- Choose the country --</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Write some message ..." style="height:100px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="bt" value="Write" onclick="writeFile()" />
    </div>

  </div>
  
<p>Submission Number: <a id="clicks">1</a>

  <div class="output-area">
    <h4>Output</h4>
    <div id="output" class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span></span>

</body>
<script>
var clicks = 1;

  let writeFile = () => {

    const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
    const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
    const submissions = document.getElementById('clicks');


    let data = [ 
      `<p>Name: ${name.value}</p>`, 
      `<p>Age: ${age.value}</p>`, 
      `<p>Email: ${email.value}</p>`,  
      `<p>Country: ${country.value}</p>`,  
      `<p>Message: ${msg.value}</p>`,  
      `<p>Submission No: ${submissions.innerHTML}</p>`]; // Use innerHTML here
 
   
    $('#output').append("<br />" + "<br />");

    data.forEach(line => $('#output').append(line));
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }


</script>

</html>
```

Generally you could of course also insert the `clicks` variable directly (instead of the contents of the `a` element).

**Note**
It is highly insecure to render user-input into your HTML. It creates all sorts of vulnerabilities for malicious users so **DON'T** do this in production.

Answer (score 3):

`<a>` tags don't have a `value` attribute. You'll have to use `textContent` or `innerText` to get the count.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('clicks').textContent);
```

```html
<a id="clicks">2</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so `submissions` is not a input element and so it does not have the `value` method.

Instead of using `submissions.value` use `submissions.innerHTML`.

Also, rearrange the last few lines to make sure the clicks counter is updated before outputting all the data.

**Edit: I did not realize your clicks counter was initially `let clicks = 1;` and not `let clicks = 0;`. The rearranging in the below JS will only work if `clicks` is initially set to `0`.**

**I would generally advise to use `let clicks = 0;` because it makes more sense to potentially yourself and another person reading your code. If you think about it - when you make your counter (`clicks`), there have not been any clicks yet and so it would make more sense to have it initially set to `0`.**

```
let clicks = 0;

const writeFile = () => {
  const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
  const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
  const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
  const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
  const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  const submissions = document.getElementById('clicks');

  // ++ is same thing as += 1
  clicks++;
  submissions.innerHTML = clicks;

  let data = [ 
    `<p>Name: ${name.value}</p>`, 
    `<p>Age: ${age.value}</p>`, 
    `<p>Email: ${email.value}</p>`,  
    `<p>Country: ${country.value}</p>`,  
    `<p>Message: ${msg.value}</p>`,  
    `<p>Submission No: ${submissions.innerHTML}</p>`
  ];
 
   
  $('#output').append("<br />" + "<br />");

  data.forEach(line => $('#output').append(line));
}
```